# Deprecation warning for integration test on http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, integration-testing, nokogiri

I'm using MiniTest and in an integration test have the line:

```
assert_select response.header['Content-Type'], "application/json"
```

It however responds with:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
>   unexpected ';' after '[#Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000064b2e58 @type=:CHILD_SELECTOR, @value=[#Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000064b3268 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["application"]>, #Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x000000064b2ef8 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["json"]>]>]' (called from block in class:SessionsTest> at (byebug):1)

Does anyone understand what this causes and how to (alternatively) test the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`assert_select`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select) is used to check an expectation in a DOM object, generally a view result.

What you should probably use in your case is `assert_equal`. Also note that, in `assert_equal`, the expectation is the first argument.

```
assert_equal "application/json", response.header['Content-Type']
```

Comment: Thanks, `assert_equal "application/json; charset=utf-8", response.header['Content-Type']` worked.